# How to "pass on" a variable number of arguments to NSString's +stringWithFormat:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, variadic-functions

I would like to write a function in Objective-C such as the one below, that takes a variable number of arguments, and passes those arguments on to `+stringWithFormat:`. I know about `vsnprintf`, but that would imply converting the NSString 'format' to C and back (and would also mean converting the formatting placeholders within it as well...).

The code below compiles, but of course does not behave as I want :)

```
NSString *estr(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, args];
    va_end(args);
    return s;
}
```

Basically: is there a `va_list`-friendly version of the `+stringWithFormat:` method, or is it possible to write one?

Comment: Just to demonstrate that this isn't just a toy example, I'd love to use such a method here as well:  http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/different-nslog

Comment: Yes indeed! NSLog is way too chatty, makes it hard to read sometimes. What I had in mind is a very simple way of internationalizing my apps... I want to write something like tr(@"Can't open file %@", filePath); for example, and have this simply be returned as-is (properly formatted) in early stages of development, then later on have a tool that finds all the tr() calls, creates the needed resource files for translations from the calls it found, then later on I just flip a switch and the tr() calls actually do lookup and translate the messages they're passed...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[initWithFormat:arguments:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithFormat:arguments:)

```
NSString *estr(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease];
    va_end(args);
    return s;
}
```

they don't seem to have a convenience constructor "stringWith..." version

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much, I was looking at the wrong place (plus, I forgot the call to 'autorelease'). This works!

Comment: You're correct, they don't have a convenience method equivalent. I filed a Radar (#7025084) a few months ago requesting this exact thing. If you want this functionality, please report a bug requesting `+[NSString stringWithFormat:arguments:]` and reference this Radar number — duplicates (there is one already) are the best developers can do at "voting" on issues they consider to be important. http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Note: To simplify triage, if you file a duplicate bug, please use component name "NSString" and version "X". Thanks!

Comment: Apple's not likely to add a convenience constructor that amounts to a one-line wrapper around an existing -init... method.

Just put it in a category on NSString.  I do it all the time.

Comment: This, like so many Cocoa brainf*cks, could be done with nary a thought in even the most basic shell, etc.  I swear, Objective C makes me wan to run for the hills because of crap like this..

Comment: @alexgray: You run for the hills over a simple method call?

Comment: Per @NSResponder:
- (NSString*) format:(NSString*) format, ... 
{ return estr(self, format); }

usage: [@"almost %@", @"pythonic"];

But how would one write it directly as a method - without invoking the C function (I got a bad access error)?

Comment: @chrisco: `+ (NSString *)format:(NSString *)format, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease];
    va_end(args);
    return s;
}`