# vsnprintf and gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, printf

I have the following statement:

```
vsnprintf(target, size - 1, "%ls_%ls", str16_1, str16_2);
```

Why does this fail on gcc?

I used this on Windows like this:

```
vsnprintf(target, size - 1, "%S_%S", str16_1, str16_2);
```

and it's working as expected. On gcc documentation I found that %S is synonym with %ls, but I must not use it. I tried also with %S, but is not working. I use this in a function with variable argument list. Is it possible to not work because I change the format variable that I pass to va_start? I must search %S and replace it with %ls in format variable.

The function is something like:

```
void f(const char* format, ...){
  char* new_format = format with %S replaced with %ls;
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(args, format);
  vsnprintf(str, size-1, new_format, argptr);
}
```

I checked and new_format is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: Felics, for the future, please insert code by four spaces (or use the `101010` button above the editor window).

Comment: _"Do you know why this fails on gcc?"_ No, but I might guess pretty well if I know __how__ it fails. Does it fail to compile? Does it cause crashes? Does it produce unexpected results?

Comment: It produces unexpected results(empty string)

Comment: @Felics:  So what are `str16_1` and `str16_2`, and where do you assign their values?  Exactly how are you examining the output?  Why do you show that you are passing strings to vsnprintf in your examples, given that that shouldn't even compile?

Comment: str16_1 and str16_2 are an example as what argptr would be inside f() function to know that I'm using 16 bit chars.

Comment: Aside from confusing snprintf with vsnprintf, your problem is that 16-bit wchar_t is a bug unique to Windows. Sane systems have 32-bit wchar_t capable of representing all of Unicode.

Comment: Replace `va_start(args, format);` with `va_start(args, new_format);` and your program should work. Also, add `va_end(args);` in the end. Please see [typical *vsnprintf* program here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vsnprintf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I use this on Mac I found a work-around:

[How to "pass on" a variable number of arguments to NSString's +stringWithFormat:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420421/how-to-pass-on-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-nsstrings-stringwithformat)

It seems that vsnprintf can't handle 16 bits string. Maybe because wchar_t isn't 16 bits.

Answer (score 8):

Try using `snprintf`, the reason being `vsnprintf`. `vsnprintf` takes an argument of type `va_list`, not a literal variadic argument list. For example:

```
va_list ap;
va_start (ap, first_arg_in_this_function);
vsnprintf (buf, size, format_str, ap);
va_end (ap);
```

Whereas with sprintf:

```
snprintf (buf, size, format_str, x, y);
```

Use `v*printf` when...

1. Making wrappers around printf style functions
2. Variadic macros are not an option

Otherwise just use `*printf`

Comment: The function is a around printf style function. It is used inside a wide char string class.

Comment: @Felics:  The fundamental problem that Joe D is pointing out is that you are passing the wrong arguments.  You are passing what appears to be two strings (of some form or another) rather than a va_list.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `va_start` is incorrect. In this statement:

```
va_start(args, new_format);
```

you are not referring to the `format` parameter of the `f()` function. The second argument to `va_start()` *must* refer to a parameter in the formal parameter list of the function. Anything else is likely undefined behaviour.

The compiler uses the named formal parameter in `va_start()` to determine where to start looking for the variable argument list in the function call. It doesn't automatically know where you put `...` in the argument list (perhaps you might expect that it should, but that's not how it works).

Comment: I found that is a mistake an corrected it, but I have the empty string as a result anyway...
First time I tried like you said and and I had an empty string and after that I changed format with new_format...

Answer (score 2):

I looked up `%ls` for `vsnprintf` and found that this is the format specifier for printing/formatting a string of wide characters i.e. `wide_t  *p = L"Hello world!";`

It took a bit of playing and googling wide character usage in C++ (I liked the following page: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/51836), but I think I figured out your problem.

If you pass in a `char` string to `%ls` then it doesn't expand, but if you pass in a `wchar_t` string to `%ls` **then** it prints.

Consider the following example code I based on your information:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>


char       str[100];


void f (const char    *format,
        ...)
{
    va_list    args;

    va_start(args, format);
    vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), format, args);
    va_end(args);
}




int
main ()
{
    char    *p1 = "1234";
    char    *p2 = "abcd";

    wchar_t    *pw1 = L"9876";
    wchar_t    *pw2 = L"wxyz";



    f("%d_%d", 120, 199);
    printf("numbers: %s\n", str);


    f("%s_%s", p1, p2);
    printf("char*: %s\n", str);


    f("%ls_%ls", p1, p2);
    printf("wide char* with char* input: %s\n", str);


    f("%ls_%ls", pw1, pw2);
    printf("wide char* with wide char* input: %s\n", str);


    return (0);
}
```

I compiled this with g++.

```
make newtest.exe
g++ -g -c -MD -Wall -Werror  newtest.cxx
g++ -o newtest.exe newtest.o -lc -lrt

Compilation finished at Thu Jul 29 08:54:57
```

Output is below:

```
[SUSE10.1]:201> newtest.exe
numbers: 120_199
char*: 1234_abcd
wide char* with char* input: 
wide char* with wide char* input: 9876_wxyz
```

Comment: I use u16 as chars(unsigned shorts). These are used in a String class that is working on Windows/Visual Studio and I must port it on iPad. This was the only problem that I had with the class until now, but I found an work-around using NSString class.

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf`.

Comment: I have same result with snprintf function, an empty string

Answer (score 0):

What is your `valist` type? The correct type for variable list arguments is `va_list` with an underscore, no?

Comment: typedef __darwin_va_list va_list;

It was a typo mistake, I use va_list. I'm sorry, I'll correct that