# Functionality of sprintf for NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, printf

How can I get the functionality of [`sprintf`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer/The_C_sprintf_Function) in Objective-C? The function is of course part of `stdio` in C, so I could certainly invoke it, but since I'm using Foundation, I need it to work with `NSString`s as well.

### EDIT

I apologize for my inarticulateness, but I'm actually hoping for something more like the [PHP `sprintf` **function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) that returns a string. (This was perhaps slightly evident before Josh Caswell's very efficient edit of my question.) It would be like `NSLog` but instead of writing to console would give a string (or pointer) as a return value.

Comment: Advice: next time you want to use `sprintf()` in C, don't use it, and use `snprintf()` instead (there's a 99% chance you'll avoid nasty buffer overrun errors.)

Comment: I apologize if you think my edit confused your question. You should feel free to re-edit however you like. Let me suggest, though, that succinct titles are generally best around here. As for the information you're seeking, why create a new function? Any such will have to create an `NSString` via a method call _anyways_, so just use the built-in method directly. If you already have a (mutable) string, there's also `appendFormat:`

Comment: Hi Josh, succinctness is certainly a virtue, esp. with titles. Your edit was fine, but washed away some of my incompletely articulated points. "Why create a function?", you ask.  I ask you: Why type the same lengthy code over and over again? Maybe you have more time than you know what to do with, but most of us don't. I'm still trying to piece out the overarching design behind Objective C, but it's pretty clear to me so far that developer convenience wasn't a prime motivation.

Comment: Why to type the lengthy code over and over again? For an extremely important point: readabilty. General rule: the burden should be on the writer, not the reader. Not relevant of course if you are forever the only person reading your code. In that case you can wrap everything into 1-2 letter function names to save writing.

Comment: Like I said: "developer convenience". That's both writing and reading. If the bracket syntax were easy for humans to read, we'd all be using RPN to do math on a blackboard. I don't see how the functional wrapper provided by CRD, for example, fails in readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
NSString *OCSprintf(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);

NSString *OCSprintf(NSString *format, ...)
{
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, format);
   NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease];
   va_end(args);
   return result;
}
```

This just wraps `stringWithFormat:` (more precisely, one of its cousins) as a function as you requested. The `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)` ensures you still get format string checking.

Comment: Thanks! This is really cool! Or it would be. But for some reason it's not working for me. XCode terminates the app and complains that `GCC does not allow format attribute in this position of a function definition` about `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)`, and also that `Class method '+stringWithFormat:arguments:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`. Indeed I don't see that method in the Dev Library. Am I missing something?

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420421/how-to-pass-on-a-variable-number-of-arguments-to-nsstrings-stringwithformat) I found a substitute for the `NSString *result...` line: `NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args] autorelease];`. That, and commenting out the `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)` makes XCode stop complaining. It works, but alas there's no format string checking.

Comment: @JohnK: All three `…WithFormat:…` methods are also listed in the NSString documentation. `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` and other `__attribute__`s can't be used in a function definition, only a declaration.

Comment: @PeterHosey - Thanks for the fix, I had it that way and just abbreviated it when copying - a bad practice!

Comment: @PeterHosey/JohnK - You are both right, there is no +stringWithFormat:arguments - it turns out I'd added that in a category as a shorthand for +alloc/-initWithFormat:arguments. Apologies for my sloppy cut'n'paste of this answer :-(

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys! Would it be out of line for us to call this `NSSprintf`? Perhaps we'd be trading on Apple's namespace (actually NextStep's), but if these guys were actually doing their job, they would have supplied this function.

Comment: @JohnK - using the NS prefix for anything is at best not wise. I picked OC for O(bjective-)C, but you can call it what you like!

Answer (score 8):

The closest function that does the same thing in Cocoa is `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat`.

Using `sprintf`:

```
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "Line %d of %d", currentLine, totalLines);
```

Using `stringWithFormat:`

```
NSString res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Line %d of %d", currentLine, totalLines];
```

Note that `stringWithFormat:` supports printing of Cocoa objects with `%@` format specifier.

Comment: Thanks, dasblinkenlight. Is there any way to get a functional wrapper for `stringWithFormat:`? Concision is not the primary virtue of Objective C and I really appreciate the old syntax. It would be something like `NSLog` but the return would be a string/NSString.

Comment: @JohnK You can write a small wrapper for `stringWithFormat:`, but unfortunately there is nothing built in for it.

Comment: @JohnK: It's simpler as a macro than a function IMO. `#define FORMAT(args...) [NSString stringWithFormat:args]`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"...", params…];
const char * myStrPtr = [myString UTF8String];
```